# Cant Read xml file using sax Parser with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xml-parsing, nokogiri, sax

I am using ruby 1.9.3 with rails 3.1. My requirement is that there is a parser file like below. when i opened with browser; Tags are not aligned in order. After the `<item>`; the data are clubbed format. There is a presence of

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

when I opened in sublime text; it shows after the `<item>`

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

also after the `</item>` there is `]]>` present. The data needs to be parsed are inside this `<item></item>`. the method called `parse_file` form Nokogiri called only `start_element, end_element`. When we tried manually by editing the file via removing the above statements; then it will call the `characters` method to fetch the data. Below is the example code.is there any other way?.

```
<batch transactionType="HC"><item><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><C><CI><Ve>00501</Ve></CI></C></item></batch>
```

Comment: Please don't use an image to convey data used to test your code. We can't reuse that and have to type it in so copy and paste the minimum data necessary to demonstrate the issue. Also, if its link rots and breaks your question won't make any sense. Please read "[mcve]". "Please provide an automated solution for this."? We want to see your effort toward solving the problem. SO isn't a "give me the code" site, instead we help you fix the code you wrote. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)” is useful.

Comment: i am sorry for my words are little bit frank. i will edit the question. But i have tried all the ways to fix this issue..  the reason i put this image to show how the xml currently show in browser. I believe there is no other way to show this . Is there anyway to fix this ..

Comment: We still need to see your effort toward solving the problem otherwise it looks like you want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using "xml-simple". Assuming your XML file name is "test.xml", first install the gem:

```
 gem install xml-simple
```

Then, you can try:

```
require "XmlSimple"

abc = XmlSimple.xml_in File.read("test.xml")

puts abc['item']
```

The output should be:

```
{"C"=>[{"CI"=>[{"Ve"=>["00501"]}]}]}
```

Comment: `require': cannot load such file -- XmlSimple (LoadError)

Comment: Aah, please install.
gem install xml-simple

Comment: Can you please post output of:-
linux/mac - which gem
windows - where gem

Comment: Please put in the effort to correctly format your answer. Also note that this is a Nokogiri question, not an XmlSimple question. We understand you're trying to help, but that means working within the requirements of the question and providing an answer that is easily readable.